# How to kill an enemy with the body of another enemy?

Tags: rochard

The **Kiss Me Deadly** achievement in Rochard requires you to kill another human enemy using the body of another enemy. Unfortunately it seems that you can't pick up the bodies of enemies directly with the G-gun, which would be the obvious way to accomplish this. So how do you kill another enemy with a body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you can pick up enemies with the G-gun and launch them into enemies. You just have to wait until

> you're in the Casino for the second time, where you'll switch your G-gun with the Helga, a more powerful gravity gun that can pick up human enemies

Comment: This part is so fun.